# How do you express this relation between two sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have two sets: Set $A = \{20, 5\}$ and set $B = \{3, 8, 5, 4\}$. As you can see, the elements of set $A$ are sum and average of the elements of the set $B$. That means value of every element of $A$ depends on values of all of the elements of $B$. My question is, how do we express this dependency in a formal way? Thanks!

Comment: I would want the relation to ignore the specific ways (sum, average) of the elements of set A, as to how they are related to set B. The relation between the sets should only express the notion that every element of A depends on the entre set B and ignore the concepts of sum, average etc..

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure what you are looking for but 
$$a_1 = 20 = \sum_{j=1}^{|B|} b_j = 3+8+5+4$$
and 
$$a_2= 5 = \frac{1}{|B|} \sum_{j=1}^{|B|} b_j = \frac{a_1}{|B|} =5$$
where $|B|=4$ stands for the number of elements of the set $B$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually looking for an expressionn relatng the two sets. How do they relate to each other? Is there any name for such relation?

Comment: @Viswa I dont think there is a special name. Lets call them Viswasets :)

Comment: good idea :) __

Comment: I'll make the wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

One way of viewing this dependency is considering two functions $s,a: \mathcal P_{fin} \left({\mathbb{R}}\right) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that given a finite subset $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have $s(X) = \sum_{x \in X}x$ and $a(X) = \frac{s(X)}{\lvert X \rvert}$. In your example we have $A = \{s(B)\} \cup\{a(B)\}$.

Comment: Is it possible to express it without using the example notions of sum.average etc. Can we use the abstract notion of every element of A depends on all elements of B?

Comment: Yes, and this abstract notion is a function. Generally speaking, a function between two power sets. In the example you gave the relation happens to involve the notions of sum and average.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "depends on" is an extremely vague notion.

- Does $4$ depend on $2$?
- Does $17$ depend on $2$?
- Does every element of $\{11, 12, 13\}$ depend on all of the elements of $\{2, 3\}$?

Let's look at that last question in particular. I wrote those two sets down first without thinking about them - so in that sense, the answer should be no. But *after the fact*, I can find a dependency! Namely, we have:

- $11=2^1+3^2$: given a set $\{a_1<a_2<...<a_n\}$, we can take $i$th power of the $i$th element and add them all up - that is, look at $\sum_{1\le i\le n}a_i^i$.
- $12=3(3+2)-3(3-2)$: take the largest element, multiply it by the sum of the elements; and from that, subtract the largest element, multiplied by the *diameter* of the set (the difference between the smallest element and the largest element).
- And $13=2\cdot 2+3\cdot 3$, the sum of the squares of the elements.

Note that each of these three operations makes sense for any finite set - so $\{11, 12, 13\}$ **does** depend on $\{2, 3\}$!

The discrepancy is that the notion of "depends on" isn't just a relation between two *sets*, but rather between two *definitions of sets*: it is **intensional**, rather than **extensional**. We can try to formulate extensional versions, but they will differ from your intuition in various ways. For example, one version would be to say "$A$ depends on $B$ if every element of $A$ is [definable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_set) from the elements of $B$" in the sense of model theory. That's great, except for two things:

- Definability only makes sense in a *background structure* - so we need to fix some structure (say, $\mathbb{N}$ with $+$ and $\times$) containing $A$ and $B$. That's easy to do, but different choices of structure will yield different notions of definability, so this isn't really fully extensional.
- Definability is more powerful than you might think! For instance, in $\mathbb{N}$ with $+$ and $\times$, *every* natural number is definable - so any set of natural numbers depends on any other set.

Comment: Extremely good answer. Sorry I don't have enough credit to upvote it. However, I do have some issues with your answer. Will list them shortly.

Comment: The dependencies I have listed, do not "select" elements from B to define the dependency. The dependency (sum, average, count) interacts uniformly and identically across all the elements. Elements of B are invisible to the dependency, but the set B is.

For example, the author name of a book, or it's page count do not refer to each page of the book, but they refer to the entity called book. A is a set of such elements, which refer to other sets, while interacting with each elements of the target set in a uniform fashion (without selection).

Comment: I do agree with your notion of seperating the dependencies from the set A. So I create a new picture now. We have a new set C = {sum, average} and its application on the set B produces the set A.

In other words, A is a set of proramming logics which process the target set B to produce set A.

Comment: So, A = f(B). or more correctly, A = C(B)